# Disable item on change the same item from previous select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, html.dropdownlistfor

I have two select combobox with same items in it.

I want to do is when i select any item from first combobox, then the item with same value should be disable in the second combobox.

here is the image what i want is:
[image]

I have used library is : http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

and my tried code is:

```
       $("#select_first").dropdownchecklist({maxDropHeight: 150,
                onComplete: function(selector) {
                    var values = "";
                    for( i=0; i < selector.options.length; i++ ) {
                        if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].value != "")) {
                            $("#select_second").children('option').each(function() {
                                if ( $(this).val() === selector.options[i].value ) {
                                    $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

My jsfiddle for the same is [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PcXXX/)
Please add solution in this.

Please give the solution if you have.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean after selecting any item from first combobox that item should be disabled from second one. Can you give a demo in jsFiddle!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code you are disabling the **< option >** only but the second control needs to be refreshed to include the updated property attributes.

```
$("#s2").dropdownchecklist("refresh");
```

So after making any change on the control you must refresh it to make it work.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/GMpLE/)

Comment: I have already used this code as i have mentioned in question itself.
i want this solution for dropdownchecklist :http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Answer (score 3):

refer this.
i got soln from this..hope this will help to you also...
http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Comment: Thanks Dear, but this is the official link. there are no solution for my exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out | **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WUN5a/1/)**

HTML

```
<select id="select1" onchange="fix(this,'select2')">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option>First value</option>
    <option>Second Value</option>
    <option>Third Value</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" onchange="fix(this,'select1')">
    <option> - Select one</option>
    <option>First value</option>
    <option>Second Value</option>
    <option>Third Value</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="set(this)">value1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="set(this)">value1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="set(this)">value2 <input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="set(this)">value2<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="set(this)">value3 <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="set(this)">value3<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="set(this)">value4 <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="set(this)">value4<br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function fix(dis,elem)
{
    var value = dis.options[dis.selectedIndex].text;  

    var ele = document.getElementById(elem);
    for(var i=0;i<ele.options.length;i++)
    {
        if(ele.options[i].text == value)
        {
            ele.options[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else
        ele.options[i].style.display="block";
    }

}
function set(dis)
{
     var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
        if(ele[i].getAttribute('type')=='checkbox')
        {
             if(ele[i].value == dis.value)
             {
                 if(ele[i].disabled)
                     ele[i].disabled = false;
                 else
                  ele[i].disabled = true;   
             }

        }
    }
    dis.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,
i am using dropdownchecklist see here : http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html
and i want exactly same functionality in this one as you have implemented.